# How parse the jsoup Elements attributes?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Haves second html  block in page:

```
<div class="card card-hover card-visited wordwrap job-link js-hot-block">
    <img width="100" height="50" alt="Micro Focus" class="preview-img preview-img-logo" src="//i.work.ua/employer_design/3/4/6/106346_company_logo_3.png">
    <h2 class="add-bottom-sm"><a href="/jobs/2052763/" title="Java Full-stack developer, вакансия от 10 августа 2018">Java Full-stack developer</a></h2>
    <span><b>Micro Focus</b></span>&nbsp;
    <span>· </span>
    <span>Киев&nbsp;· </span>
    <span><span class="label label-hot">Горячая</span></span>
    <p class="overflow"> Полная занятость. Опыт работы от 2 лет. Высшее образование.
    <br> SERENA Software (www.serena.com), part of&nbsp;MicroFocus group, is&nbsp;the global leader in&nbsp;Application Lifecycle…<a href="/jobs/2052763/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></p>
</div>
```

How to fulfill the condition, using jsoup:

> if href equals "/jobs/2052763/" then return "Micro Focus" ?

I can find href "/jobs/2052763/" and can find "Micro Focus" (element/attr("alt")), but cannot tie with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Elements result =
  doc.select("h2:has(a[href*=\"/jobs/2052763/\"]) + span > b");
```

Choose child (`>`) `b` of preceded sibling (`+`) `span` of `h2` having (`:has(...)`) `a` with attribute `href` value `/jobs/2052763/` (`[...]=...`).

Comment: Wow, I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Find `<a>`, move two parents up and select `img`:

```
Element link = doc.selectFirst("a[href=/jobs/2052763/]");
System.out.println(link.parent().parent().selectFirst("img").attr("alt"));
```

Comment: Super method! But selectFirst() not present in Document class(?), however select() work well. Thank you!

Comment: Use `.select(...).first()` or upgrade your Jsoup.